# What exactly do the injections the time travellers get do?

Tags: 12-monkeys-2015

If I remember correctly, in the first few episodes they made a lot of of fuss about the preparation a time traveller must undergo until he can travel more or less safe and in one piece. This involved a long term treatment with injections.

Later it seems as if the only preparation a time traveler needs is just one injection seconds before he/she splinters. And it also seems more of a beacon for the splinter machine to be able to lock on the target.
Also over time there are more and more handy side effects of the injections revealed (what seems like a somewhat lame deus ex machina to me) like stopping aging, rapid healing, immuninity to time line changes and possibly more.

So what exactly do the injections do? What are they for? Where there different injections over the course of the series? Where they improved or did they have all the current effects from the very first episode on?